# Prove that $f$ is continuous at $(0, y_0)$. where $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Prove that f is continuous at $(0, y_0)$

$f(x, y) =
\begin{cases} (1+xy)^{1/x} &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
e^y & \mbox{if } x \equiv 0. \end{cases} $

Thank you!

Comment: For the second case do you mean $x=0$?

Comment: Yes! I am thinking of using the property that $(1+x)^{1/x}$ = $e^x$. But don't know what to do next.